# Angular call service on asynchronous data

Tags: angularjs

I have a service that make some calls to retrieve data to use in my app. After I've loaded data, I need to call another service to make some operations on my data. The problem is that second service will not have access to the data of the first service.

I've made a plunker: [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/2fERik4uTxbxlVOhncMd?p=preview)

**First service**

```
app.factory('Report', ['$http', function($http,$q){
var Authors = {

    reports : [],
    requests :[{'url':'data.json','response':'first'},
               {'url':'data2.json','response':'second'}, 
               {'url':'data3.json','response':'third'}]

};

Authors.getReport = function(target, source, response, callback) {
    return $http({  url:source, 
                    method:"GET", 
                    //params:{url : target}
                }).success(function(result) {
                    angular.extend(Authors.reports, result)
                    callback(result)
      }
      ).error(function(error){
                })   
}

    Authors.startQueue = function (target,callback) {
        var promises = [];
        this.requests.forEach(function (obj, i) {
            console.log(obj.url)
            promises.push(Authors.getReport(target, obj.url, obj.response,  function(response,reports){
                callback(obj.response,Authors.reports)
            }));
        });
    } 


return Authors;
```

}])

**Second service**

```
app.service('keyService', function(){
this.analyze = function(value) {
    console.log(value)
    return value.length
}
});
```

**Conroller**

In the controller I try something like:

```
    $scope.result = Report.startQueue('http://www.prestitiinpdap.it', function (response,reports,keyService) {
        $scope.progressBar +=33;
        $scope.progress = response;
        $scope.report = reports;

    });

$scope.test = function(value){
    keyService.analyze($scope.report.about);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are going for?  Essentially, you want to call the second service after the first succeeds.  There are other ways of doing this, but based on your example this is the simplest.

http://plnkr.co/edit/J2fGXR?p=preview

```
$scope.result = Report.startQueue('http://www.prestitiinpdap.it', function (response,reports) {
    $scope.progressBar +=33;
    $scope.progress = response;
    $scope.report = reports;
    $scope.test($scope.report.about); //added this line
});

  $scope.test = function(value){
    $scope.example = keyService.analyze(value); //changed this line to assign property "example"
  }


  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl"> 
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <p>Progress notification : {{progress}}!</p>
    <div ng-show="show">
    <progress percent="progressBar" class="progress-striped active"></progress>
    </div>
    <pre>{{report}}</pre>
    <pre>{{report.about}}</pre>

    {{example}} <!-- changed this binding -->
  </body>
```

Comment: The other ways to do this is with promise deferred?